# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Hello guys  am new around i am facing a problem in the class mentioned below all  am trying to do is to provide program name as a parameter and return the program link from the database this is my code .

```
public String getLink (String Program){

    String Program_Link=null;

    try {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        Connection mycon=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/programinformation","root","");
        PreparedStatement mystmt=mycon.prepareStatement("SELECT Program_Link from program_table where Program_Name=?"); 
        mystmt.setString(2, Program);       
        ResultSet rs=mystmt.executeQuery();

        System.out.println("The link acquired is"+rs.getString("Program_Link"));

        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        }
    } catch (Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Program_Link;    
}
```

But i am getting the following error

```
Connecting to a selected database...
Connected to database successfully...
Creating statement...
Statement created ...
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4110)
    at com.TvToday.StarSystems.TSMService.getLink(TSMService.java:35)
    at com.TvToday.StarSystems.Process.doPost(Process.java:36)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Server Responding from doPost Method  !!!
```

Comment: After you entered the question title, how did you miss the list of related questions which popped up below the title? You can see them once again in the "Related" section on the right hand column. How exactly were those related questions unhelpful in answering your concrete problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error message captures the problem accurately; your SQL is:

```
SELECT Program_Link from program_table where Program_Name=?
```

which has 1 placeholder (coded via a question mark), but you attempt to set the value for the *2nd* placeholder:

```
mystmt.setString(2, Program);
```

So, it explodes. Try changing the `2` to `1`:

```
mystmt.setString(1, Program);
```

---

You have a bug there too. If the driver fails to load (which hasn't been required for over 10 years btw), you catch the exception, print the error message, **but keep going regardless**. If you catch an exception, either work around the problem or log it and return. Otherwise, don't catch it at all.

Comment: Thanks  Bohemian it worked out for me but now i am facing this before start of result set error. As i said its only been a few weeks since i have started working.

Comment: rs.getString("Program_Link") shoud follow rs.next(). So you either move the first System.out.println() in the while(rs.next()) loop or you comment it out.

Comment: Hasn't this question been asked countless times before? Couldn't you just find and/or polish up a canonical dupe and vote for close?

Comment: thanks to all of you my problem got sorted out cheers every one .